# CodenameOne Fontimage not recognized

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I am trying to create an icon with Fontimage but looks like it is not recognized.
Here is my Gui constructor:

```
public Gui2(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
        initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
        /-------------------------HERE-----------------------------------/
        Image icon = Fontimage.createMaterial(Fontimage.MATERIAL_KEYBOARD_BACKSPACE,"Button",5);
        this.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar("", icon, (evt) -> {
            new Gui1().show();
        });
    }
```

I did this import:

```
import com.codename1.ui.*;
```

But he doesn't recognize it.
I got this error: **`"Cannot find symbol Fontimage"`**

I don't know what the problem is

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was "FontImage" instead of "Fontimage".
It works now.